# How to locate the element of the popup window inside the page Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I'm trying to check if the page is opened after clicking the button but can't locate the element of the popup window inside the page. I tried all elements in the popup window but it's same.

The url I tried: https://www.boyner.com.tr/limon-t-shirt-911887

I'm trying to check if the page opens after clicking the "Beden Sihirbazı" button.

These are my codes:

```
public final By sizePage = By.xpath("//*[@class=\"text-h5 non-selectable text-center\"]");

//Check the is page opened
    WebElement sizeSection = driver.findElement(sizePage);
    boolean isOpened = sizeSection.isDisplayed();
    boolean desiredBoolean = true;
    Assert.assertEquals(isOpened, desiredBoolean);
```

The error I got:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy the text into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several parts to clicking the button and waiting for the dialog to appear.

Steps:

1. The button is inside a shadow-root, so we have to grab that and then search inside it.
2. The dialog that pops up is inside an IFRAME so we have to switch into the IFRAME in order to see the dialog.
3. Then we finally have to wait for the dialog frame to become visible.

The working code is below.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.boyner.com.tr/limon-t-shirt-911887");
SearchContext shadowRoot = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("usizy-adviser")).getShadowRoot();
shadowRoot.findElement(By.id("size-text")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("div.usizy_spinner_container + iframe")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.q-dialog")));
// if we get here, the dialog is visible

driver.quit();
```